# Lists Vs App. when we should use each

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, modern-experience, app

Inside SharePoint online, we now have 2 options to create lists (mainly custom lists), either:

1. Using App
2. Using Lists

As follow:

[image]

Now in our case we want to create a ticketing system, where users submit a ticket >> assign it to a specific person >> then an Power automate flow will run to send an email and modify the item permission.

Now I am planning to create this from >> App >> Custom List >> create a site content type with all the custom fields.

So is my approach valid? or I should use Lists instead?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list using **App** option is old/classic experience way.

While, Creating a list using **List** option is new/modern experience way.

For your case, to create a **custom list**, you can use either one of the options & it should work for you without any problem.

---

**Additional**:

If you want to create a new list using modern experience **list templates** or **From existing list** --> You should use **List** option.

This option provides a way to create a new list with similar/pre-defined structure like existing SharePoint list.

[image]

---

If you want to create a new list using classic experience **list templates** like **Calendar**, **Tasks**, **Discussion Board**, etc. --> You should use **App** option.

[image]

Comment: Hi @John, does this help you? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer more easily.